# View collective.documentviewer generated data in collections

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x, documentviewer

Currently it is possible to upload documents to plone4, and when using the collective.documentviewer add-on, uploaded documents will be shown within the view. It is also possible to create a collection within plone, which basically combines a bunch of selected views (at least this is my current understanding). However, if one of the views is a documentviewer-view, all that is been shown in the collection is a small [Read more...]-link.
The Idea is to get either all the converted images (documentviewer creates an image per pdf-page) shown in the collection or (more clean, I assume) to include the documentviewer itself.

I do understand that i need to make an addition or a change to the collection view as far as i know. However, i also need to receive the corresponding data from the documentviewer. And I am plain stuck in understanding how this works. I've been reading documentation for a few days now, also I've been reading through some of collective.documentviewer's code.

Currently I believe that the function which shall provide the information/url for finding the path to the image is

```
def getResourceRelURL(gsettings=None, settings=None, obj=None):
```

in ./collective/documentviewer/storage.py, which returns

```
return '%s%s/%s/%s' % (base, uid[0], uid[1], uid)
```

I would be grateful for any idea which would lead me towards the right direction.

Comment: You may ask this question on the github issue tracker: https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/issues